# Android Studio won't clear cache after upgrade to 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradlew

Just upgraded Android Studio to 3.2. Now, every time I try to use run the app or use Build > "Build Bundle/APK", "Generate Signed APK/Bundle" I get an older version of the app.

What's very strange though, is if I use terminal, cd into the android folder, and use "react-native run-android", the app builds just fine.

I feel like this is a caching issue. I've tried clearing the cache via "./gradlew cleanBuildCache", I've added "android.enableBuildCache=false" in my gradle.properties file, I've tried restarting Android Studio, restarting my computer, and nothing. Same old version of the app.

Comment: If in your gradle.properties you have:
org.gradle.configureondemand=true delete this line @AndrewTelkamp

Comment: I don't, I did finally get this working if you see my answer below, but I don't feel like this is the true answer because I have to run this in terminal every time I make an update to my app. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did get the updates to work by running the following in terminal/command...

```
1) (in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
2) react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
3) react-native run-android
```

...but I feel like there has to be something else going on here. Open to additional ideas.